# spring mvc can't receive json parameter

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

java code :

```
@RequestMapping("/addQuestion")
@ResponseBody
public Result addQuestion(@RequestParam("title") String title,
        @RequestParam("content") String content){
    Question question = new Question();
```

I use postman to send request parameters
postman :

```
Reqeust Header:
Content-Type:application/json

Request Body:
{
"userId" : 1,
"offset": 0,
"limit":10
}
```

return result：

http code：400

```
"timestamp": "2019-02-20T06:39:41.223+0000",
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"message": "Required int parameter 'userId' is not present",
```

I don't know if the problem is on postman or not,i think java code should be ok.....

help me ... thanks... man

Comment: Paste code, remove images.

Comment: where is this userid validation ?

Comment: had modified it

Comment: This would work, but not for json but for form submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case you should use `@RequestBody` instead of `@RequestParam`.

```
@PostMapping("/addQuestion")
@ResponseBody
public Result addQuestion(@RequestBody Question)
```

`@RequestParam` is for handling query parameters, but you want to handle the request's body, thats what `@RequestBody` is for.

Comment: I understand ,thanks

Answer (score 0):

In spring framework we have at list three annotations which allow us send some data through request:

```
1) public void createUser(@RequsetBody User user) {
          ...
   }
```

in request you should add **request body** it is actually your case you sand request body:

```
Reqeust Header:
Content-Type:application/json

Request Body:
{
"userId" : 1,
"offset": 0,
"limit":10
}
```

but your controller is waiting for @RequestParam

```
2) public void addUserName(@RequsetParam String userName) {
          ...
   }
```

in request you should add query params like this:

```
Http Params

userId : 1,
offset: 0,
limit:10
```

3) In case if you have only one or two params you can use @PathVariable

```
@GetMapping("/users/{userId}")
public User getUser(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId) {
          ...
}
```

request should looks like this serviceUrl/apiUri/users/123

Comment: Gread!!~ I understand,thanks